# html 5 hidden input type file required validation

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML5 client-side validation on my web form. All fields are working perfectly, but my file field is not displaying the required error because input type file is hidden by CSS.

My code is:

```
<input id="imageUpload" class="form-control"  type="file" name="image" placeholder="Photo" capture required>
```

Comment: You should remove your "required" tag at the end.

Comment: then it will not work.

Comment: What has this got to do with php? Where's the javascript? Maybe include the relevant CSS that you claim may be the issue?

Comment: i am not using javascript just php and html

Comment: @hasnain the tags are there for the code in question, not what your whole project contains.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that browser can not focus hidden elements. Simple fix would be to use `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`.

```css
#imageUpload {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="imageUpload" class="form-control" type="file" name="image" placeholder="Photo" capture required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```